# Bootstrap columns on same row when html is not adjacent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html code that uses bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h1>DIV1</h1></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"><h1>DIV2</h1></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h1>DIV3</h1></div>
<div>
```

It is working fine for all devices except xs. On extra small devices I want DIV1 and DIV3 on same row (on first row).

I want to maintain the layout as it is for all other devices.

Comment: You can change the divs order with display flex and order, but the navigator support is limited (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it via css and bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6"><h1>DIV1</h1></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12"><h1>DIV2</h1></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6" id="div3"><h1>DIV3</h1></div>
</div>
```

And the css for third div:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #div3{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add additional styling to achieve this as the divs will generally follow after each other. You could set positioning to absolute and with additional bottom margins for the other two place the middle one below.